# How can I use (Node) Livereload on a development server in my network

Tags: node.js, gulp, livereload

Background: My PHP projects (CakePHP, Wordpress) run on an Ubuntu server in my network, I access them through a development TLD (.dev for example) setup through a local DNS server and I edit the files through a Samba share.

I would like to utilize Livereload for my development, preferably have it running on the server itself. I have basic Node/Gulp knowledge, but haven't been able to get this running.

Livereload (or a middleware server) should proxy the 'real' URLs, making sure all websites run as they would normally and Livereload should be available over the network (so not just localhost, because that runs on the development server)

Desired result:

Livereload runs on my dev server (IP: 10.0.0.1), my project is called helloworld.dev, I browse to 10.0.0.1:3000 on my machine and see helloworld.dev proxied through Livereload. I now edit a CSS file over the Samba share and the CSS is reloaded without a refresh.

I've tried using a few NPM packages, gulp-livereload, livereload, node-livereload, with their provided examples that come with the packages, but haven't been able to get the desired result. They all expect you to run in locally, don't support access to the Livereload URL over the network, cannot proxy the 'real' URLs or require static content.

Can anyone provide an example or 'proof of concept' code of my wish, so I can see where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: http://nitoyon.github.io/livereloadx/
This does EXACTLY what I need.

I can run

```
livereloadx -y http://helloworld.dev -l
```

open

```
http://serverip:35729
```

and I'm ready to roll.

The -y option creates the proxy to the 'real' URL and the -l makes it serve files from local filesystem instead of through its proxy.